# How to place the tick label between grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a grid and I want two changes.  The first is that I want the y-axis tick labels to be descending starting from the top. I have managed to do it but I was wondering if there was a simpler way. The second is that I want the tick labels to be between the grid lines and not at the location of the grid lines. This is my current MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
# Set aspect ratio to be equal
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.grid()
```

In this case I would like the tick labels to be from 0 to 9 and to sit in the middle between the grid lines on the x and y axes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of achieving this is to use `.set_xticks()` and `.set_yticks()` with `minor=True` which setting minor ticks at every location from  -0.5 to 9.5 on both the `x` and `y` axes as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the x and y ticks
ticks = np.arange(0, 10)
plt.xticks(ticks)
plt.yticks(ticks)

# Set the x and y limits
plt.xlim(0, 9)
plt.ylim(0, 9)

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
# Set aspect ratio to be equal
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

# This is my suggestion
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 10, 1), minor=True)
plt.gca().set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 10, 1), minor=True)
# Omit extra tick marks
plt.gca().tick_params(which='minor', length=0)

plt.grid(which="minor") # don't forget to add this to enable grid lines at the locations of the minor ticks

plt.show()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I don't want the extra tick marks. Can they be omitted?

Comment: You're welcome. I already update the code above to omit extra tick marks. Don't forget to mark it as answer if  you think this answer your question. Happy coding!